# Return only the portion of a line after a matching pattern

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I need help to work on a COMMAND where it is a `*` (star) delimited file has a multiple lines as mentioned below. I want to search for a line which starts with `NM1*IL` and extract the last column. Below is the example shown.

```
$ cat temp.txt
NM1*IL*1*RESTAR*FRENNY*M***MI*99358358~
N3*2164 Boeing Avenue~
N4*NEW DELHI*CA*94114~
DMG*D0*19550610*F~
NM1*PR*2*KFHP*****PI*94135~
NM1*IL*1*STAR*FRENY*M***MI*99358958~
NM1*IL*1*RESTA*ANNIE*M***MI*993583589~
```

I want the output as below

```
99358358
99358958
993583589
```

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong with your code because you did not provide it or the errors you encountered. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep 'NM1[*]IL' temp.txt | awk -F'*' '{print $NF}' | sed 's/~$//'`

You can run parts of this pipeline (up to and not including `|`) to see what the particular commands do to your input.

`grep 'NM1[*]IL'` — filter the input lines so that only the ones matching this pattern are left. `grep` takes a regular expression as its argument and `*` is a special regex character (meaning 0 or more of the symbol it follows) so it needs escaping. I used a *character class* here (`[]`) because I think it's neat. Could have used `NM1\*IL` to the same effect.

`awk -F'*'` — `-F` specifies *field separator*, which I set to `*`. Awk splits every input line into *fields*, so anything in between two `*`s is a field for awk.

`'{print $NF}'` is the awk program it will now execute on its input. It says "for all input lines print the field with number `NF`" where `NF` is a special awk variable, it stands for "number of fields". So what it does is print the last field.

`sed 's/~$//'` — just strip the trailing `~`. `$` means end-of-line. So this sed substitutes any tildas preceeding EOL with an empty string. Could have written `tr -d '~'`, but this sed is more precise (only strips tildas before EOL).

[`grep(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html), [`awk(1p)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html), and [`sed(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) are all standard UNIX command line utilities. Study the man pages for more information on how to use them.

Comment: Bingo...! Its Perfectly worked . Thanks a lot buddy @ Vladislav Ivanishin. Could you please explain the command..

Comment: As an alternative, grep can be skipped and the task can be completed with awk and sed. `cat temp.txt | awk -F'*' '/^NM1\*IL/{print $NF}' | sed 's/~$//'`

Comment: @BlackPearl oh yeah, that's neat! (And the `cat` is useless, so `awk -F'*' '/^NM1\*IL/{print $NF}' temp.txt  | sed 's/~$//'`)

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation  @ Vladislav Ivanishin. Once gain thanks for time and support.. :)

Comment: all that could be done with *just* awk, instead of a pipeline of grep, awk and sed. eg. `awk -F '[*~]' '/^NM1\*IL/{print$(NF-1)}'`

Comment: I have another requirement as below  1. List item

How to replace only date part to current date of all files present in diretory in unix 
Folder path : C:/shan
Sample files:
CN_Apria_837p_20180924.txt   
DN_Apria_837p_20150502.txt    
GN_Apria_837p_20160502.txt    
O/p should be :
CN_Apria_837p_20190502.txt    
DN_Apria_837p_20190502.txt    
GN_Apria_837p_20190502.txt

Comment: @Shankar looks like a fairly trivial use case for ´sed´. Also, I don't see how this is related to the original question, so consider posting a new one (or better, familiarize yourself with basic features of sed).

Comment: I couldn't able to post the another question due to time limit .since it is very urgent am asking help from you here . Kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is tagged `linux`, I assume that you're using GNU grep:

```
$ grep -oP '^NM1\*IL.*\*\K.*(?=~)' /tmp/file
99358358
99358958
993583589
```

This is using `pcre` syntax with look-behind and look-ahead zero-width assertions -- the stuff matched up to `\K` and inside the `(?=...)` won't be included in the output when the `-o` option is used.